# Does Tangram support updates?

Tags: perl, orm, tangram-orm

I have a few questions regarding the [Tangram](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tangram/) ORM.
Can some Tangram guru advise what does it mean that Tangram has [no support for SQL UPDATE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tangram%3a%3aSucks)?
Also, is this ORM in general a good choice and in what cases?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it does support SQL UPDATE. Solving another problem (*partial column select* -- I hardly understand what it means) *might* result in such inability. That's how I've read the doc you linked to.

My experience with Tangram is very limited, though.